# Binary tree count using OpenMP threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

This is code that counts number of elements in binary tree. I tried to understand the code but I can't. I don't understand how `left_count` and `right_count` are incremented when we didn't set them to be incremented anywhere. I also don't understand the part that it is calculated if the `level` is lower than 5. In the description it says that it is due to optimizations, but how do I understand it if the tree is higher than 5 levels then it will only count up to the fifth element? I'm stuck, I would appreciate the help :D

```
template<typename T>
void countNodes(Node<T>* head, int* result, int level = 0) {
    int left_count = 0;
    int right_count = 0;

    if (!head) {
        *result = 0;
        return;
    }

    #pragma omp parallel if(level == 0) shared(left_count, right_count) num_threads(8)
    {
        #pragma omp single nowait
        {
            #pragma omp task shared(left_count) if(level < 5)
            countNodes(head->l, &left_count, level + 1);
            #pragma omp task shared(right_count) if(level < 5)
            countNodes(head->d, &right_count, level + 1);
        }
        #pragma omp barrier
        #pragma omp single 
        *result = 1 + left_count + right_count;
    }
}
```

Comment: `result` is modified. Look at how the recursive calls use that in relation to left and right count.

Comment: If the level is less than 5, no task is created, and the line is executed immediately and sequentially.

Comment: `&left_count` and `&right_count` are passed as the `result` parameter in the recursive calls, which assign to `*result`.

Comment: `omp barrier` should not be mixed with tasks. You should use `omp taskwait` if you want to wait for tasks to be executed. Btw, a `\` is missing at the end of the `omp parallel` directive and using `num_threads` is often a bad idea (please use `OMP_NUM_THREADS` instead)

Comment: as first approximation you can ignore the pragmas and the line starting with `shared(...`. Only after you understood how it works sequentially it makes sense to bother about the multithreaded variant

Comment: @VictorEijkhout this is not exactly right. Task if(0) still creates the task and you pay the cost of task creation. It only prevents the asynchronous execution of the task. The thread can only continue execution when the included task completed execution.

Comment: @Joachim Thanks for the correction. Indeed, it creates an "undeferred" task, meaning that its data environment behaves like a task, so that's indeed possible overhead. Your statement that the "thread can only continue execution" is functionally equivalent to my statement of immediate & sequential execution. I think.

Comment: When you call `countNodes(head->l, &left_count, level + 1);` you are passing in the address of the `left_count` variable, which means its value will be modified by the function.  This variable's address is passed in as the parameter `int* result`.  You can see where `*result` is assigned a value:  `*result = 1 + left_count + right_count;` thus modifying the `left_count` of the calling function. The counts are the sums of the counts of the children branches plus 1 for the node itself.

Comment: @Community If it needs additional details how come seven different people have provided relevant commentary or answers? Please.